# 302 instead of 200 when using custom AuthenticationFailureHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redirect, spring-security

When I don't specify a custom `AuthenticationFailureHandler` in my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, the request is redirected to the default "/login?error" with status 200. When I add a custom implementation which only delegates handling authentication failure to the default implementation:

```
public class SomeCustomHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

  private final SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler("/login?error");

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    authenticationFailureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
  }
}
```

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
      .requestMatchers()
      .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
    .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
      .formLogin()
      .loginPage("/login")
      .failureHandler(new SomeCustomHandler())
    .permitAll();
```

}

I receive 302 and redirection to no-error login page. Could anyone explain why?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is `/login?error` redirecting to `/login` because it is secured.

When you do not have a custom failure handler Spring Security is aware of your login URL and your login failure URL.
By adding `.permitAll()` to your configuration Spring Security will allow all requests to both the login URL and the login failure URL, since it knows what they both are.

When you add a custom failure handler, Spring does not know what your login failure URL will be, or even whether you will have a failure URL, since you are handling that logic yourself.
Therefore `.permitAll()` is only applied to the login URL.
If you don't want `/login?error` to be secured, you will have to set that configuration yourself. You can do something like:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
...
```